# IndexOutOfRange in Constructor C#

Tags: c#

I've got simple class, something like this:

```
public class myClass
{
    public static readonly string[] stringArray= { "one", "two" };
    private string myString;

    public myClass (int _index)
    {
       if(_index > (stringArray.Length - 1) || _index < 0)
       {
           throw new IndexOutOfRangeException("Bad index.");
       }
       else
       {
           myString = stringArray[_index];
       }
    }

}
```

I'm running simple constructor: myClass example = myClass(5); and I've got error. 
It shouldn't leave constructor without trying create new object?

I don't understand how throw works there.

---

Edit: Sorry, I made a mistake. There should be **stringArray.Length -1** in if section.

Comment: This is not a duplicate.  The OP has a type in his code and he needs help.

Comment: Do you not understand why your exception is being thrown, or why throwing an exception in the constructor will cause the object to not be initialized?

Comment: I just want something like that:
myClass example = myClass(1); -> It's ok, I've my object
myClass example = myClass(5); -> Write error in Console.

Comment: What is the question here: why myClass example = myClass(5); throws an expcetion ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are passing 5 as the `_index` to your constructor the following if condition will be true

```
if(_index > (stringArray.Length - 1) || _index < 0)
```

because the length of the array is 2 an 5 > 1.  This causes the code to throw the `IndexOutOfRangeException` which stops the constructor from returning an instance of the object.  Additionally if you do not have a `try-catch` around the `new myClass(5)` then the exception will bubble up and cause your running application to crash.

Answer (score 3):

`myString` is null, so you are getting a NullReferenceException when you access the `Length` property.

My guess is that you want:

```
if(_index > (stringArray.Length - 1) || _index < 0)
```

Comment: My guess would be your guess as well.

Comment: Despite of this It still doesn't work, but I handled that kind of exception.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your code.  You need to get the length of the array not the string.

The line of code should:

```
 if(_index > (stringArray.Length - 1) || _index < 0)
```